# Runtime import in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to import a json file at the runtime.

My code:

```
const path = "../../assets/data/"+<fileprefix>+".json"
const data : Information = await import(path);
```

`fileprefix` here changes at the runtime.

I'm getting module not found error as below.

> Error: Cannot find module '../../assets/data/US.json

`US` here is the fileprefix that comes at runtime.

Is there any way I can make node to find the module at the runtime?

Comment: If someone feels this as a dumb question. Explaining the reason could help. New to typescript world here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you mean by `import`. If you are referring to the ES6 `import` (`import something from 'something'`), then, no. You can't do that. However, I see that you're doing `import(path)`. Is `import()` a library of some sort or are you expecting that to work with an es6 import?

Here's what you should do (IMO):

What you can do, is serve your json files as static files and then use the `fetch` api to bring that json in.

Ex:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Obviously, instead of the url being `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`, it would the url to your static json file.

One other option would be to get all of your json files (or references to your json files) into a single module. Then you can import that module and then call whatever method you need to call so that the correct json file comes back. Here's an article on how to go about this: https://medium.com/@leonardobrunolima/javascript-tips-dynamically-importing-es-modules-with-import-f0093dbba8e1